# Principais diferenças entre estruturar CSS com PHP e LESS/SASS

Tags: php, css, sass, less

Em muitos projetos venho escrevendo `CSS` com `PHP`, o que é uma prática bem desconhecida mas que atendente todas as necessidades de dinamização, exemplo...

**CSS**

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css");
$cor_fundo = "#999";    

?>

body {
background: <?=$cor_fundo?>;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.php" type="text/css" />
```

Pré processadores como `LESS` e `SASS` tem a mesma proposta, então qual a diferença quando comparados com `PHP`? há algum problema em escrever `CSS` com `PHP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diferença é que ferramentas como Less/Sass fornecem todas essas características de gerar um CSS dinâmico muito próximo do CSS *vanilla*. A sintaxe de um arquivo Less pode facilmente ser escrita e entendida por um desenvolvedor CSS, pois não é muito diferente do que ele está acostumado. Já fazer isso com PHP exigiria conhecer uma nova linguagem.

Arquivo LESS retirado de http://lesscss.org:

```
@base: #f938ab;

.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
}
.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
  .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
.box {
  color: saturate(@base, 5%);
  border-color: lighten(@base, 30%);
  div { .box-shadow(0 0 5px, 30%) }
}
```

Arquivo CSS resultado do código acima:

```
.box {
  color: #fe33ac;
  border-color: #fdcdea;
}
.box div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Perceba que a sintaxe é muito próxima. Inclusive, muitas ferramentas implementam uma sintaxe quando sabem que esta será implementada oficialmente no CSS futuramente. Por exemplo, já vi ferramentas que utilizavam *mixins* do sistema de *grid* exatamente com a sintaxe do *grid* presente hoje no CSS. Isso permite que o desenvolvedor possa migrar para o CSS mais moderno sem alterações em seu código.

Já, fornecer o código CSS via PHP não apresenta nenhum problema grave. Enviando corretamente os cabeçalhos da resposta HTTP e formatando corretamente o CSS, não terá problemas. Uma diferença é que enquanto as ferramentas como Less/Sass geram um arquivo CSS estático, o PHP gerará o arquivo a cada requisição; isso pode afetar o tempo de resposta da requisição dependendo diretamente do tempo de execução do código PHP. Uma das vantagens de se utilizar o PHP para gerenciar isso é a facilidade de controlar todos os cabeçalhos da resposta HTTP, principalmente os relacionados ao cache.

Abaixo uma lista compilada das diferenças citadas. O sinal ✓ ao lado indica qual ferramenta apresenta melhores resultados para cada característica conforme minha opinião:

1. Sintaxe do código;

   - LESS/SASS aproximam sua sintaxe para o *vanilla*; ✓
   - PHP possui uma sintaxe completamente diferente;
2. Tempo de resposta;

   - LESS/SASS geram um arquivo CSS estático; ✓
   - PHP demanda ser executado a cada requisição, podendo aumentar o tempo de resposta;
3. Necessidade dos cabeçalhos da resposta HTTP;

   - LESS/SASS os cabeçalhos são gerenciados pelo próprio servidor; ✓
   - PHP demanda que você controle manualmente os cabeçalhos;
4. Gerenciamento dos cabeçalhos HTTP;

   - LESS/SASS os cabeçalhos são gerenciados somente pelo servidor;
   - PHP possibilita que você gerencie todos os cabeçalhos; ✓

Outra possível diferença também pode estar na possibilidade de enviar o CSS via *server push* do HTTP/2. Não sei afirmar se das formas formas seria possível de forma equivalente.

Answer (score 2):

A diferença é que o PHP processa no **lado do servidor**, ou seja para o usuário vai realmente chegar um arquivo CSS. Já que o front-end não interage diretamente com o back-end.

Já o LESS/SASS e afins **podem** ser processados pelo navegador usando JavaScript, o que ocorre no **lado do cliente**, exemplo com LESS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

No entanto dependendo da configuração você pode converte o less para css no lado do servidor também, usando Node.js ou então libs de terceiros.

Note que geralmente as pessoas convertem por linha de comando os arquivos LESS e SCSS/SASS, exemplo com LESS:

```
lessc meusestilos.less meusestilos.css
```

Exemplo com SCSS:

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

Como citei antes é possível usando Node.js resolver diretamente no lado do servidor, mas acaso não possa ter o Node.js em seu servidor, existem a soluções de terceiros que citei anteriormente para "compilar" (processar) LESS, SCSS e SASS com PHP para CSS:

- https://github.com/leafo/lessphp
- https://github.com/leafo/scssphp
- https://github.com/panique/php-sass

> **Nota:** O SASS possui uma série de ferramentas para diferentes linguagens, que eles mesmos indicam: http://sass-lang.com/libsass

Uma coisa importante para citar é que LESS e SASS/SCSS possuem muitas funcionalidades prontas, claro que se você só usa o básico do CSS, então o seu script PHP deve atender bem, acaso queira mais funcionalidades então seria interessante estudar um deles, less ou scss, a escolha vai conforme a sua necessidade.

---

Aproveite e de uma lida nisto:

- [Qual é a diferença entre SASS e SCSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54453/3635)