# Problema para converter SCSS par LESS

Tags: svg, less

pessoal estou usando um background feito com svg desse link [aqui](https://codepen.io/zessx/pen/ZGBMXZ) porem a paleta de cores dele esta com `SCSS` e estou utilizando o `LESS` como posso converter esses elementos para o `LESS`? tentei colocar o `@` no lugar do `$` mais não funcionou segue o código em `SCSS` que preciso converter para `LESS`

SCSS:

```
$colors: (
  #feda3e,
  #cc6698,
  #0869ad,
  #ff8300,
  #7A86b8,
  #f05133,
  #2aa9e0,
  #71bf45,
  #ef0e39,
  #9e79d7,
);
$color: nth($colors, random(length($colors)));

#bg {
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, @color 0%, darken(@color.toHSL, 50%) 100%); 
}
```

LESS:

```
@colors: 
  #feda3e,
  #cc6698,
  #0869ad,
  #ff8300,
  #7A86b8,
  #f05133,
  #2aa9e0,
  #71bf45,
  #ef0e39,
  #9e79d7
;
@color: nth(@colors, random(length(@colors)));

#bg {
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, @color 0%, darken(@color, 50%) 100%); 
}
```

ERRO AO CONVERTER:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc testou com CSS Variables? Acho que não deu certo pq essa última linha parece um Mixin de SASS e no LESS deve ser de outra forma provavelmente.

Comment: meio que descobri o problema vou refazer a pergunta

Comment: o problema está nessa sequencia de código 
#bg {
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, @color 0%, darken(@color 50%) 100%); 
}

O less não reconhece esse Darken ai nãos ei o motivo

Comment: Cara pelo CodePen parece que o Exemplo não é SASS é SCSS tem algumas diferenças... Olha aqui um exemplo https://futurestud.io/blog/content/images/2014/Jun/sass-vs-scss.png aqui vc pode ler a respeito https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54453/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sass-e-scss

Comment: entendi eu consegui fazer o array de cores via less o problema e que essa linha de código não consigo converter pra less você saberia me dizer como ficaria  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, $color 0%, darken($color, 50%) 100%); parece que o problema é esse darken não sei se ele e chamado de uma forma diferente no less porque quando eu compilo da erro nele

Comment: @hugocsl coloquei um print do erro para ver se consigo esclarecer melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

São dois problemas: o primeiro é que você está utilizando funções que não existem no LESS, o segundo é que a função [`darken()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken) requer uma cor válida, e no caso do seu código isso não está ocorrendo.

Você está tentando obter um valor aleatório da lista, porém se utilizar essa variável `@color` da forma que está, verá que o valor dela não é uma cor: [ver no editor online do LESS](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40colors%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%23feda3e%2C%5Cn%20%20%23cc6698%2C%5Cn%20%20%230869ad%2C%5Cn%20%20%23ff8300%2C%5Cn%20%20%237A86b8%2C%5Cn%20%20%23f05133%2C%5Cn%20%20%232aa9e0%2C%5Cn%20%20%2371bf45%2C%5Cn%20%20%23ef0e39%2C%5Cn%20%20%239e79d7%5Cn%3B%5Cn%40color%3A%20nth(%40colors%2C%20random(length(%40colors)))%3B%5Cn%5Cn%23bg%20%7B%5Cn%20background%3A%20%40color%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Você pode utilizar *javascript evaluation* (não encontrei na documentação mais recente, depois edito com o link) para utilizar funções do Javascript em meio ao código LESS, por exemplo: [`Math#random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) e [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Para extrair um item de uma lista, você deve usar a função [`extract()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions), então, com *javascript evaluation* você pode especificar o valor máximo com base no `length` da lista:

```
@colors: 
  #feda3e,
  #cc6698,
  #0869ad,
  #ff8300,
  #7A86b8,
  #f05133,
  #2aa9e0,
  #71bf45,
  #ef0e39,
  #9e79d7
;

@len: length(@colors);
@color: extract(@colors, `Math.round(Math.random() * @{len})`);

#bg {
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, @color 0%, darken(@color, 50%) 100%); 
}
```

#### [ver resultado online](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40colors%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%23feda3e%2C%5Cn%20%20%23cc6698%2C%5Cn%20%20%230869ad%2C%5Cn%20%20%23ff8300%2C%5Cn%20%20%237A86b8%2C%5Cn%20%20%23f05133%2C%5Cn%20%20%232aa9e0%2C%5Cn%20%20%2371bf45%2C%5Cn%20%20%23ef0e39%2C%5Cn%20%20%239e79d7%5Cn%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40len%3A%20length(%40colors)%3B%5Cn%40color%3A%20extract(%40colors%2C%20%60Math.round(Math.random()%20*%20%40%7Blen%7D)%60)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%23bg%20%7B%5Cn%20background%3A%20radial-gradient(ellipse%20at%20center%2C%20%40color%200%25%2C%20darken(%40color%2C%2050%25)%20100%25)%3B%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D)

Comment: Resultado no codeopen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpoZKj