# SassCSS undefined variable usando RGBA

Tags: css, django

Quando tento usar uma variável de um arquivo .scss, com uma variável funciona e outra não:

_templateColors.scss

```
$blue-dark : #0277bd !important;
$gray-light : #f5f5f5 !important;
$gray-dark : rgba(51,51,51,0.08) !important;
```

Arquivo que usa essas cores:

```
@import "../../../core/static/scss/_templateColors.scss";

#left_nav{
    background-color: $gray-dark;
}
```

Quando uso as variáveis `$blue-dark` e `$gray-light` funciona normal, porem o a `$gray-dark` não.

Erro:

```
Error: Undefined variable.
  ╷
4 │     background-color: $gray-dark;
```

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o seu problema...

Comment: Cara isso não é SASS isso é SCSS, pode ser alguma config do seu compilador

Comment: Editei e coloqueis SassCSS.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre SASS e SCSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54453/3774)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz uma cópia do arquivo templateColors para a mesma pasta do outro arquivo e deu certo. Aparentemente deve ser pq o sass não estava "assistindo"(wathcing) o diretório do template.